# Order creation in sage accpac 300 erp version 5.5 in c#

Tags: c#, accpac

I am new to sage Accpac Erp. I want to create order in sage accpac 300 erp version 5.5 using .net API (c#) . I am struggling to find the sites for sample code to create order in sage accpac. I referred following sites

http://www.pluscommunity.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=31441&page=1

https://smist08.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/entering-orders-and-headerdetail-views/

But still I wasn't able to find the proper source code. Please advice me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to start the process by using the built in VBA macro recording functionality and enter a sales order.  That will give you all of the steps that you need to create a new sales order via code.

You'll have two steps after that:

1. Convert the source code from VBA to C#
2. Add the steps required to make the connection to Accpac from your application.  The macro recording won't contain these steps because in order to record a macro you've already made a connection to Accpac.

As Ram noted, www.tek-tips.com has several examples that visitors have posted when looking for the same sort of help.

Comment: is there any articles on how to convert from vba to C# specific to accpac?